# pg_restore: [archiver] could not open input file. No such file or directory

Tags: docker-compose, docker-volume

I want to import a database that is saved on Windows into a PostgreSQL container on Docker.

After building and publishing the containers successfully, I run the Docker containers using `docker-compose up –d` and then try to import the database into the project.

```
user@DESKTOP-A2MVLM4 MINGW64 ~/dockerProjectImage (master)
$ docker-compose exec db pg_restore -U fewo -h localhost --dbname=dbName backups/backup.psql
```

On Windows, I have the the following directory structure:

[image]

and now I try to import database `backup.psql` from folder named `backups` which has the `backup.psql` file.

But I get an error:

```
user@DESKTOP-A2MVLM4 MINGW64 ~/dockerProjectImage (master)
    $ docker-compose exec db pg_restore -U fewo -h localhost --dbname=dbName backups/backup.psql
    pg_restore: [archiver] could not open input file "backups/backup.psql": No such file or directory
```

while the directory and file both are available.

**docker-compose.yml:**

```yaml
version: '2'
services:

  web:
    image: image-url-web:latest
    links:
      - db
      - memcached
      - solr
    ports:
      - 8080:80
      - 8443:443
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www

  solr:
    image: image-url-solr:latest
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8700:8700"
      - "8710:8710"
      - "8720:8720"
      - "8730:8730"
    restart: always

  db:
    image: image-url-db:latest
    ports:
      - "8032:5432"
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: dbName
      POSTGRES_USER: dbUser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'password'
      POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS: '-E SQL_ASCII'
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/backups

  memcached:
    image: memcached:1.4.31
    restart: always
```

Answer (score 4):

Per your screenshot, you have a `backups` directory on your Windows system. It seems to be at the same level as the directory you are sitting in at the point you run your `docker exec` command (based on the shell prompt in your example).

However, what matters is what is available *inside the container*. The command you run using `docker exec` is running inside your container, not on your Windows system directly. The container in question here is the `db` service, which has a volume mount defined in `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
db:
   volumes:
    - ./:/var/www/backups
```

This will mount the base directory (the one where `docker-compose.yml` lives) at `/var/www/backups` inside the container.

From your screenshot, I cannot tell where `docker-compose.yml` lives, but your command text example suggests that it probably lives in `~/dockerProjectImage`. So that is the directory mounted at `/var/www/backups`.

From that point, you cannot reach the `backups` directory shown in your screenshot. It is outside of `dockerProjectImage`, so it will not be part of the mount.

One way to fix this would be to move the `backups` directory inside `dockerProjectImage`. Then it would become available inside the container as `/var/www/backups/backups/`. However, that still won't work the way you wrote your command (probably) because you are using a relative path (`backups/backup.psql`). You would need to specify the full path, e.g.

```
docker-compose exec db pg_restore -U fewo -h localhost \
    --dbname=dbName /var/www/backups/backups/backup.psql
```

Comment: I followed the same steps as you have mentioned above. Here **/** in `/var/www/backups/backups/backup.psql` is assumed to the **C:/Program Files** and gave the following error:

`$ docker-compose exec db pg_restore -U fewo -h localhost --dbname=dbName /var/www/backups/backups/dbName.psql

pg_restore: [archiver] could not open input file "C:/Program Files/Git/var/www/backups/backups/dbName.psql": No such file or directory`

Comment: @DeepakPathak Your screenshot and question don't mention anything about `C:\Program Files\` so I couldn't tell you what is happening there. I would just be making a random guess since there's not any information about that directory in the question. You may need to add more detail to your question in order to allow people to come up with potential solutions.

Comment: Just to make this clear for someone new: `./:/var/www/backups` means to mount from the docker-compose file's directory (`.`) to a volume inside the container (`/var/www/backups`). You can choose any directory you like for the volume. For example, if you want the file to be seen in backups in the home directory, you need to mount it to `/home/backups` (not: `~/backups`, absolute path needed). Put the dumped db ("*.sql", "*.dump", ...) in the same dir as that of the docker-compose file. If you enter the container's bash you find it in either `/var/www/backups` or `~/backups` as you put it.